# Can D.Va hide behind teammates to protect herself from her own Self Destruct ultimate?

Tags: overwatch

D.Va's ultimate Self Destruct will do damage to her if she's within line of sight of her mech, so by hiding behind cover, D.Va can avoid being killed by her own ultimate.

**Is it possible for D.Va to use her own teammates as cover to protect herself from her own ultimate?** So, for example, could a D.Va player hide behind a friendly Roadhog to avoid taking from her own ultimate?

Comment: I doubt a roadhog would work, but I wonder if a friendly *barrier* would

Comment: @DarthPizza, you may wish to switch your accepted answer to jojo's, as a recent patch has changed this (now D.Va is immune to her self-destruct and simply no longer needs to hide)

Comment: @DoktorJ Yuuki's answer is the one that helped me at the time when it was relevant, so I will leave it as the accepted answer. Just upvote the most up-to-date one, it's timestamped anyways.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Long overdue update to this answer: [D.Va can no longer self-damage with her ult](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747185139?page=1#post-4), so this question/answer is moot.

Previous answer:

D.Va can't use allied hitboxes or allied barriers to block self-damage from her ultimate. She can, however, use an *enemy* barrier (Winston's or Reinhardt's, but not Zarya's as it is targeted) to block self-damage.

Comment: Mei's Ice Wall also works.

Comment: As addition: She can also not use enemy hitboxes to block the damage. https://youtu.be/LzuapRj_LeA?t=1m54s

Comment: What about hiding behind a friendly Mei that just Cryo-Freezed herself? I read that Mei can be used as cover in those situations, but I'm not sure if that applies for when you're trying to avoid damage from your own D.Va ultimate.

Comment: You may want to change the wording. At a glance I though you meant Dva not being immune to her ult was the "long overdue update"

Answer (score 19):

As of [today's patch,](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747185139) the player who casts Self-Destruct is now immune to their own explosion:

> Self-Destruct
>
> - Ultimate cost decreased by 15%
> - Explosion delay reduced from 4 seconds to 3 seconds
> - **Explosion no longer damages D.Va (the player who activates it)**