# Will D.Va's ultimate damage players on her team?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed while playing D.Va that her ultimate can kill her and that it can kill members of the other team, but I'm not sure what the situation is with members on her team.

I've often noticed that everyone just runs away, sometimes an enemy Reinhardt will put a shield up to protect himself and manages to survive.

I want to know this, because when using the ultimate I would prefer to use it in such a way that people on my team will survive, I've tried a few times to check if they died, but I've not been able to put my finger on it.

Will D.Va's ultimate damage members of her own team?

Comment: [Patch Notes July 19, 2016](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747185139) - [the player who casts Self-Destruct is now immune to their own explosion](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276001/126536)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, D.Va's ultimate will not damage her teammates.

In general, no abilities can deal damage to teammates. The only direct way to kill a teammate is to do something that pushes them of the map.

If you see the 'TEAM KILL' notification in the center of your screen, that is actually to denote that your team has wiped the enemy team, not that you've killed a teammate.

In the case of Reinhardt's shield, it can block any damage (except for Symmetra's moves, Winston's gun, Junkrat's Rip Tire, his own Fire Strike ability, and Hanzo's Spirit Dragon) as long as it has at least 1HP. So a 1HP Reinhardt Shield can take the full 1000 Damage of D.Va's explosion.

Comment: +1 Yet, it would seem that a lot of people don't know that and run away from it.

Comment: Reinhardt shield also cannot block melee damage, his own Fire Strike ability, Junkrat's Rip Tire, or Hanzo's Spirit Dragon. Not particularly relevant to this question, but might as well complete the list.

Comment: His shield can block the damage from junk rats tire, not the tire itself.

Comment: It's also worth noting D.Va's ult won't damage herself anymore.